# How to represent data base in swim lane diagram?

Tags: analysis, business-intelligence, bpmn, processmodel

I'm modelling a process of *police dispatch systems* with `swim lane diagram`.

I want to show that all the actors (operators that receive calls and police personnel) access one common database.

What are various ways to represent databases in `swim lane diagrams`?

And I want to show that police dispatch system is interfaced with ambulance and fire services.

How can i show this interface?

Answer (score 2):

BPMN knows a data store symbol for persistent data living independent from your process instances and shared in between them. Furthermore you can model the interface to other services by making use of closed pools and collaborate in between your fully modeled process and other (eventually external) processes by making use of message flows in between them. See an illustrating quick'n dirty example below.

[image]

Comment: Hi @user3468536 - you are welcome. In this case it is practice on stackoverflow to express your opinion by upvoting the answer and/or marking it as the definitive answer to your question. Many greetings!